# Como renombrar pdf masivamente con PYTHON en Subcarpetas

Tags: python

necesito reenombrar .pdf masivamente para carpetas y sub carpetas, estoy utilizando libreria OS en PYTHON. Para este ejemplo necesito quitar archivos llamados 123.pd.pdf
gracias de antemano

De esta manera funciona solo para la carpeta principal no para las subcarpetas

```
import os
pdf_directory = '/Desktop/pruebas'
Carpeta = os.chdir(pdf_directory)

for Nombre in os.listdir():
    print(Nombre)
    #print(os.path.splitext(Nombre))
    texto, extension = os.path.splitext(Nombre)
    if Nombre.lower().endswith(".pdf") and '.pd' in texto.lower():
        texto = texto.replace('.pd','.pdf')
        os.rename(Nombre,texto)
    print("FIN")
```

De esta manera recorre todas las carpetas pero genera errores.

````
```rootDir = '/Desktop/pruebas'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    #print('Directorio encontrado: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        #print('\t%s' % fname)
        if fname.lower().endswith(".pdf") and '.pd' in fname.lower():
            newpdf = fname.replace('.pd.pdf','.pdf')
os.rename(fileList,fname)
print("Fin")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Soluciones

No entraré en detalle con cada solución, ya que internet se han [hecho muchos tutoriales](https://www.google.com/search?q=recorrer+recursivamente+directorios+python&oq=recorrer+recursivamente+directorios+python&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB7SAQg4MTk0ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) con respecto al tema de recorrer recursivamente directorios, aunque casi nada usando pathlib. Sin embargo, explicaré algunas cosas.

os.Scandir busca solo en el directorio actual, por lo que no es tan simple como iterar sobre él. No podrás aplicarlo a tu proposito sin crear una función recursiva.

En el segundo código, el error se debe probablemente a que no pasaste los argumentos correctos a `os.rename` (`fileList` es una lista de cadenas, no una cadena que represente a un directorio) además, `fname` sería el nombre original del archivo, por lo que, incluso sin el problema antes mencionado, no verías ningún cambio. Además, no es necesario ejecutar os.rename si le vas a dejar el nombre como está, por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
rootDir = '/Desktop/pruebas'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
        if fname.lower().endswith(".pdf") and '.pd' in fname.lower():
            newpdf = fname.replace('.pd.pdf','.pdf')
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirName, fname), os.path.join(dirName, newpdf))
print("Fin")
```

**Edit** Parece que filelist es una lista de nombres de archivo, no un directorio entero (ejemplo, fname sería "hola.pd.pdf" en el caso del directorio "sub/hola.pd.pdf"). Arreglado usando os.path.join con dirName (el código está sin probar)

Recomiendo, sin embargo, que si estás en versiones de Python por arriba de la 3.4, uses los modulos [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/es/3.12/library/pathlib.html) o [glob](https://docs.python.org/es/3.12/library/glob.html) (en python 3.5), ya que estos tienen utilidades para recorrer directorios recursivamente y el primero tiene algunas ayudas extra. Pathlib ofrece el método `rglob`, que es compatible con los comodines y sirve justamente para recorrer recursivamente directorios.

##### Consejo

No uses `in` y `replace` para buscar y eliminar sufijos. Imagina que te topas con un archivo que dice "hola.pd.pdfesa.pd.pdf", este se renombraría bien en cuanto a la extensión, pero el nombre cambiaría de un modo no deseado: `hola.pdfesa.pdf`.

En su lugar, recomiendo quitar el sufijo así

```
filename[:-len(".pd.pdf")]
```

El código anterior elimina los ultimos `len(".pd.pdf")` caracteres.

Y luego creas una nueva cadena agregando el sufijo correcto:

```
filename[:-len(".pd.pdf")] + ".pdf"
```

Y listo! A prueba de errores! Solo recuerda ponerlo dentro de un condicional para asegurarte de que ese sufijo está presente.

En Python 3.9 o superior, existe el método de cadena [removesuffix](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix), pero para mantener la compatibilidad con versiones anteriores, prefiero seguir usando la tecnica antes mencionada.

Comment: Hola @Dante S. gracias por tu respuesta sin embargo, me genera un error: 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'Pruebasconpd.pd.pdf' -> 'Pruebasconpd.pdf'   
Este archivo esta dentro de la carpeta, en una subcarpeta, 
tu codigo realizo el cambio en los archivos que están afuera (en la ruta principal), Gracias de ante mano

Comment: @FabianManosalva De nada! Y gracias por avisarme! No lo probé, pero se supone que ahora debería de funcionar.

Comment: Hola @Dante S. gracias, si los renombra, pero lastimosamente saca los archivos pdf de todas las carpetas al directorio principal y eso me generar un caos. me podrías ayudar a que se renombren dentro de cada carpeta. (y si no te molesto si llega a encontrar un nombre repetido se renombre con +1 o algo asi ) 
gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Arreglado. Sobre lo que me pides entre parentesis, eso ya va más allá del error del código, y si lo hago por vos, estaría perjudicando tu aprendisaje (parte de aprender en la vida, es practicando). Sin embargo, te informo que ningún modulo de la librería estandar hace eso automaticamente, por lo que esa parte te toca hacerla vos mismo. Y suerte!

Comment: Te agradezco @Dante S. ya soluciona el error. Gracias por tu enseñanza.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes renombrar todos esos archivos en todavía menos líneas de código usando tanto [`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) como `re`.

```py
import re

from pathlib import Path

for pdf in Path('directorio').rglob('*.pd.pdf'):
    new_path = re.sub(r'(.*)\.pd\.pdf$', r'\1.pdf', str(pdf))
    print(f'Renombrado de {pdf} -> {new_path}')
    pdf.rename(new_path)
```

Y tendrás algo por el estilo:

```bash
$ python recorrer.py
Renombrado de directorio/sub1/archivo1.pd.pdf -> directorio/sub1/archivo1.pdf
Renombrado de directorio/sub1/archivo2.pd.pdf -> directorio/sub1/archivo2.pdf
Renombrado de directorio/sub1/archivo3.pd.pdf -> directorio/sub1/archivo3.pdf
Renombrado de directorio/sub1/archivo4.pd.pdf -> directorio/sub1/archivo4.pdf
```

Y te quedas flipando.

Este código no tiene mucha explicación. Basicamente con Pathlib busco recursivamente un patrón, luego uso expresiones regulares para buscar el ".pd.pdf" y cambiarlo tan solo por el ".pdf" y luego se renombra.

Comment: Me parece overkill usar regex. Sin embargo, es genial ver a parhlib en acción

Comment: Me gustan las regex en estos casos por mi paranoia de que me gusta que lo que matchee, esté al final exactamente como sufijo. Osea, quiero reducir el dominio de búsqueda a cosas como "archivo.pd.pdf" y no a posibilidades como "archivo.pd.etc.pdf". Solo cuestión de gustos y paranoias.

Comment: Aunque ahora que lo pienso, con el rglob ya tendrían que eliminarse esas posibilidades. Espero. Tanto QA testing con cosas exóticas en el trabajo me hace dudar de todo

Comment: Podés lograr esa misma certeza con if pdf.endswith(".pd.pdf"): pdf = pdf[:-len(".pd.pdf")] + ".pdf", incluso sin que rglob ayude con eso